# pyspark. Generate list based on values in multiple columns

Tags: pyspark

I'm new to pyspark, but I've done some research and can't seem to find an answer to my problem. I have a dataframe where I can have repeating entries in the streetID col. I need to create a (sorted) list of houseNums, based on the streetID.

```
+---------+---------+
|streetID |houseNum |
+---------+---------+
|      890|    12445|
|      400|    35840|
|      890|    28980|
|      639|    35840|
|      639|    12445|
+---------+---------+
```

The result would hopefully look like this. Do I need a UDF for this, or are there in built APIs that can address this problem? Any suggestions?

```
+---------+--------------------+
|streetID |houseNumList        |
+---------+--------------------+
|      400|    [35840]         |
|      890|    [12445, 28980]  |
|      639|    [12445, 35840]  |
+---------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) which returns a list of objects with duplicates.:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df.groupBy("streetID")\
   .agg(F.collect_set("houseNum").alias('houseNumList')).show()
```

To `sort` each the elements in list`ascending` order, you can include the function [`sort_array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array.html):

```
(df.groupBy("streetID")\
   .agg(F.sort_array(F.collect_set("houseNum").alias('houseNumList')).show()
```

which will `order` your numbers in ascending order within the lists.